# How to create object in IOS similar to JAVASCRIPT

Tags: ios

How can i create an object which is similar in javascript?

```
    var writers = {
            publicAccess: false,
            ids: []
    };
```

Please help ?

Comment: Search for `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `NSDictionary`.

The quickest way to create this is the following:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"publicAccess": @NO,
                        @"ids": @[@"id1", @"id2"] };
```

With the full Objective-C syntax, and if you don't want a static dictionary, it could go:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:@NO forKey:@"publicAccess"];
[dict setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"id1", @"id2", nil] forKey:@"ids"];
```

Comment: it might be not the best way to use literals to explain such a thing to a newbie. it may confuse them.

Comment: @holex : Agreed. I'll add the classic Obj-C syntax.

Comment: @holex can you help me for one more issue, that here i dont need any elements in NSMutablearray"ids", in javascript it just declared without initializing. How can i done in ios?

Comment: @user3615680, if you don't need any elements, use this code `[NSMutableArray array]` instead of this `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"id1", @"id2", nil]`. your array will be empty but mutable enough to add/remove object to/from it later.